# Xcode 4.5 hangs when compiling large file

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, archive

I have an Xcode project I want to archive.

However, the archive takes a very long time and trows an error: Xcode can not compile a file with about 19.000 lines.

- Is there a limit on the number of lines Xcode can compile?
- Is there a way to actually get Xcode to compile this file?

**EDIT:**
I have to note that this file only contains some parsed content, i.e. is a data model which can not be split.
I know it could be extracted into a database of some sort, but the question is really about Xcode and its compiling behaviour.

Comment: why do u have a single file with 19k lines :D:D

Comment: Try AppCode... heard it is better than XCode :p

Answer (score 2):

I changed my project to have <19,000 lines however a similar error still persisted!

what worked for me in Xcode5 after all was to change the Build Settings:  Set "optimisation level" for RELEASE (or all) to NONE. worked wonders.

Answer (score 0):

**Divide & Conquer**

What kind of code is that in a single class/file?

You could have broken that code into modules by creating other classes/objects. That would be simpler to understand and manage.

Comment: See my edit, I know about dividing code, etc. its just weird that Xcode behaves like this.

Comment: cool, you should have posted your edit before my answer. Now my answer is wrong. :(     And now you should contact apple or try AppCode for compilation behavior.

Comment: Don't worry, my fault. Should have made that clearer. I'll see what Apple support can tell me about it.

Comment: And do post the answer here itself, so that we and others get something to learn.